Rails 7.1.3 new application scaffolded forms default to HTML
A brand new application, installing version 7.1.3, is producing, as a result of habitual scaffolding forms which have a processing format of HTML.
Processing by PositionsController#create as HTML
no config settings have been touched, aside from those required for devise to run mailers
Confusion?
Expectation that the default rendering as of Rails 7 would be TURBO_STREAM.
Nothing in the rails respository for the version, or the migration guides alludes to any of change of the advertised default handling.
What is occuring here?

When investigating the structure of the application, it turns out there was no
config/importmap.rb file.
Thus, running the following in this order
./bin/rails importmap:install
./bin/rails turbo:install
./bin/rails stimulus:install

put the application back into its expected default state where forms are submitted as
Processing by PositionsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
The installer did not do its purported job...
